# Cannot configure Application to load external dll's from another folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, deployment, installation

I am trying to move my external .dll's (like DevExpress and others) to another folder called "lib".

I added following lines to my app.config file:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="lib" />
</assemblyBinding>
```

I output my .dll files to lib folder with my setup project. The application setup installs successfully but when I launch the application my splash screen (which is configured by VS2010) shows and disappears and that is all what happens. The directory structure is like this:

```
// FAILS
..\MyApp\Application.exe
..\MyApp\Application.exe.config // With assemblyBinding added
..\MyApp\lib\*.dll // All dll files are here
```

If I change the application.exe.config file to load from the base diretory and copy the .dll's back to the base directory, it runs fine.

```
// RUNS FINE
..\MyApp\Application.exe
..\MyApp\Application.exe.config // With assemblyBinding removed
..\MyApp\*.dll // All dll files are here
```

What may be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the debugger first.  If your code is swallowing exceptions then use Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox to force it to stop when the exception is thrown.  Fuslogvw.exe is a good tool to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem.  Both of your described scenarios worked for me.  More information on what error is occurring is needed.

Comment: Thanks, after debugging I saw that it was an error in app.config file. Works now!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was due to an error in config file. After fixing the error it started working.